# Proof for isomorphism $\text{Hom}_A(V,W)\cong V^*\otimes_A W$

Tags: representation-theory, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $A$ be a f.d. semisimple associative algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ with identity element. Let $V,W$ be two f.d. representation (left modules) of $A$. The dual representation (right module) $V^*$ of $V$ is defined such that $\langle f\cdot a,v\rangle=\langle f,a\cdot v\rangle$ for any $f\in V^*,v\in V,a\in A$. Denote by $V^*\otimes_A W$ the quotient space $V^*\otimes W/\text{span}\{(f\cdot a)\otimes w-f\otimes (a\cdot v):f\in V^*,v\in V,a\in A\}$. Could you give a proof for $\text{Hom}_A(V,W)\cong V^*\otimes_A W$? Thanks.

Comment: What are the assumptions on $V$ and $W$?

Comment: They are finite dimensional and semisimple.

Answer (score 2):

It is not difficult to show that if $P$ is a finitely generated projective left module over a ring $A$ then for all left $A$ modules $Q$ there is an isomorphism $\phi:P^*\otimes_AQ\to\hom_A(P,Q)$ such that $\phi(f\otimes q)(p)=f(p)q$. This is proved in most textbooks that deal with all the terms involved (Here $P^*$ denotes $\hom_A(P,A)$, with its usual right $A$-module structure)

Now if $A$ is semisimple, then all its modules are projective. If it is moreover finite-dimensional, a module is finitely generated iff it is finite dimensional. What you want is therefore just a special case of the general statement above.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I just noticed that your statement is presented in Bourbaki's book. And I need to verify that your def for $V^*$ is the same with mine. In addition, could you give more ref on this statement. Thanks.

Comment: On what statement? You found it in Bourbaki, so it is there :-)